# ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (example.com redirected you too many times) This page isn't working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am getting the browser warning:

> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS (example.com redirected you too many times) This page isn't working

Using PHP 5.6 on CentOS CWP for a PHP Script and installed SSL on the Domain. If I don't use SSL it shows an insecure warning. And after SSL install its giving **"ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"**
Don't know what to do in this situation, please help.

Below is the `.htaccess` file content:

```
    AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .php
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

## Sponsors #########################
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/members|members)/?(.*)?$ /sponsors/$2 [L,R=301]
###################################

######## eDirectory without subfolder #########################################
ErrorDocument 400 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 401 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 404 /errorpage.php
ErrorDocument 500 /errorpage.php

######## eDirectory with subfolder. Change "edirectory" for your folder name ##
######## Do not forget to remove the lines above ##############################
#ErrorDocument 400 /edirectory/errorpage.php
#ErrorDocument 401 /edirectory/errorpage.php
#ErrorDocument 403 /edirectory/errorpage.php
#ErrorDocument 404 /edirectory/errorpage.php
#ErrorDocument 500 /edirectory/errorpage.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/sugar|sugar)/(.*)?$ ./sugarCRM.php?url_full=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

######## eDirectory with subfolder. Change "edirectory" for your folder name ##
######## Do not forget to remove the line above ###############################
#RewriteRule ^(.*/sugar|sugar)/(.*)?$ ./edirectory/sugarCRM.php?url_full=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/sitemap|sitemap)\.xml$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/sitemap|sitemap)\.xml$ ./sitemap_generate.php [L]

######## eDirectory with subfolder. Change "edirectory" for your folder name ##
######## Do not forget to remove the line above ###############################
#RewriteRule ^(.*/sitemap|sitemap)\.xml$ ./edirectory/sitemap_generate.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/sitemapnews|sitemapnews)\.xml$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/sitemapnews|sitemapnews)\.xml$ ./sitemap_generate.php?news [L]

######## eDirectory with subfolder. Change "edirectory" for your folder name ##
######## Do not forget to remove the line above ###############################
#RewriteRule ^(.*/sitemapnews|sitemapnews)\.xml$ ./edirectory/sitemap_generate.php?news [L]

######## Allow all URL to open ################################################
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

######## eDirectory with subfolder. Change "edirectory" for your folder name ##
######## Do not forget to remove the line above ###############################
#RewriteRule . /edirectory/index.php [L]

###############################################################################
```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `RewriteRule` immediately following the `RewriteBase` ?

Comment: What is the nature of the redirect loop? From/To? There's nothing that relates to an HTTP/HTTPS redirect in the `.htaccess` code you've posted?